# Download a xml file from a link using a java program

Tags: java, xml, url, download, desktop-application

I am trying to create a Java program that starts up, downloads an xml file from a http web address http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat and saves it to a set location so I can then parse it for the data I want.

What I would like to know is how do I download this document from this link in java for a standard computer application?

Comment: *"parse it for the data"*  Why not parse it directly from the `URL`?

Comment: `<evec_api method="marketstat_xml" version="2.0"><marketstat>
    
   </marketstat></evec_api>`  ..what 'data'?!?

Comment: Sorry for not specifying earlier but the xml that is returned from the link is specified by adding to the link [link](
http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=34&typeid=35&regionlimit=10000002) 
so something like this will return more specific data.

Comment: Now that is more like it.  :)  Definitely go with the answer of @Kumaran.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you try the XML SAX parser provide by Java?

Here is a sample code:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/book.xml");
InputStream stream = url.openStream();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(stream);
```

Comment: You're welcome.  +1 for your answer BTW.  The answer might have gone further in detail, but as the only answer that suggests parsing directly from URL using an XML parsing API, it gets my vote. :)

Comment: Thank you for your response it gives me a good direction to go in :)

Comment: Hey Thanks Andrew & user1903093. All the best for the implementation.

Comment: Thanks. Pretty simple and useful.

Comment: Complete noob question: What do you have to import to get this stuff without errors?

Answer (score 1):

This function will get you the full content from the URL :

```
public String getURLContent(String p_sURL)
{
    URL oURL;
    URLConnection oConnection;
    BufferedReader oReader;
    String sLine;
    StringBuilder sbResponse;
    String sResponse = null;

    try
    {
        oURL = new URL(p_sURL);
        oConnection = oURL.openConnection();
        oReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(oConnection.getInputStream()));
        sbResponse = new StringBuilder();

        while((sLine = oReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sbResponse.append(sLine);
        }

        sResponse = sbResponse.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return sResponse;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The response of the URL will contain the xml, you just have to type cast it to a String and parse for the required data