# How to pull xml file from an api in an android app and make doubles

Tags: java, android, xml, api

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873308/download-a-xml-file-from-a-link-using-a-java-program), though more involved.

I need to take the xml data from this link

http://eve-central.com/api/marketstat?usesystem=30000142&typeid=34&typeid=35&typeid=36&typeid=37&typeid=38&typeid=39&typeid=40&typeid=11399

and extract the sell/min and buy/max, average them, and then do math with the results.

I would like to also store the xml data so that requests on the servers do not need to be made often.

I have a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnN8elFNx1xvdGRoeVFPU2FQNVVSeXRXX0V5STdCMGc&usp=sharing) that does what I want, I just need to emulate that in an android app.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing out to the other question at stackoverflow.

My first answer is to use the same answer than on that thread, in this case employing [SAXParser for Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html) and see what you get.

Kind regards,

Comment: 1. The first code snippet returns an error on the third line on docBuilder. 
2. How do I turn the strings that the parser returns into doubles?

Comment: For 1...i had to see that error to know what would be happening (are you using http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html ? ) For 2 a Double.parseDouble(myString) should suffice